# How to Show ads every 5 minutes in Exoplayer android

Tags: android, ads, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

i want to show ads in Exoplayer after every 5 minutes, but i am unable to it here is my code.

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
            new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)));

    MediaSourceFactory mediaSourceFactory =
            new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .setAdsLoaderProvider(unusedAdTagUri -> adsLoader)
                    .setAdViewProvider(playerView);

    player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory).build();
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    adsLoader.setPlayer(player);

    MediaItem firstItem = new MediaItem.Builder().setUri(contentUri).setAdTagUri(adTagUri).build();
    player.addMediaItem(firstItem);
    player.prepare();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

this code is showing ads only 1 time. i just wanted to know that where to and how write code for calling ads every 5 minutes.

Comment: i also tried to make parts of media and then pass it to player. like following code                     
'MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder().setUri(contentUri).setClipEndPositionMs(300000).setAdTagUri(adTagUri).build();
            MediaItem mediaItem2 = new MediaItem.Builder().setUri(contentUri).setClipStartPositionMs(300000).setClipEndPositionMs(1200000).setAdTagUri(adTagUri).build();'
it also show ads only 1 time at start. but if I give different ad url it work fine

Comment: From what I have understood, you want to load the same ad again every 5 minutes. You can set different `mediaId` for each MediaItem you create for ads. This is necessary because ExoPlayer internally uses `contentUri` as a unique id for media if we don't explicitly pass `mediaId`.

Comment: how will that be?
can you kindly help me with some code sample